# Hardening and securing Solaris 10 server

Tags: solaris-10, sparc

We have some Solaris 10 systems running on SPARC. A former manager decided not to renew support contract with Oracle so we are missing some patches for the systems. Current management is working on getting a support contract but it may take a month or so. I see Vulnerability in the Oracle Solaris product of Oracle Systems (component: Pluggable authentication module) is getting exploited in the wild https://threatpost.com/oracle-solaris-zero-day-attack/160929/

The Solaris 10 systems are behind firewalls, do not have ports exposed to Internet, but don't have an anti-virus. They are pretty old, the former UNIX server admins retired and the current ones think installing an anti-virus can destabilize the system because of its age and not having current patches. We have a plan to retire them but it will take 6 months and budget approval.

I saw the SANS article https://www.sans.org/media/score/checklists/AuditingUnix.pdf and https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/harden-unix-linux-systems-close-security-gaps on hardening the UNIX servers.

```
1. Any other steps we need to take to secure the Solaris 10 systems?

2. Anything else we need to do to increase logging to detect any malicious activity?

3. Any other services which can help as we don't have an anti-virus on them currently?
```

Comment: You already asked this question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618046/hardening-and-securing-solaris-10-server#comment1155999_618046

Comment: Yes, I asked this and was told at UNIX stackexchange that it may be suited for Serverfault so posted it here.

Comment: Please don't do anything in that SANS article to your systems if you don't understand **exactly** what the change does.  It's almost 20 years out-of-date, and if you do things like follow the recommendations in there on removing setuid/setgid from programs you can break your system.  And violate your support contract with Oracle when you do have one...